# How do I interpret the results from lmer preformed on natural log transformed data?

Tags: data-transformation, interpretation

I'm having trouble interpreting the ANOVA outputs from an lmer model performed on natural log transformed data. I know the parameter estimates and confidence intervals need to be back transformed using the exponential and the resulting back transformed estimates  are ratios/percent difference between 2 groups while all other factors are held constant. My question is this: Do the back transformed estimates represent MEAN percent difference or MEDIAN percent difference? I only ask because I just took a biostatistics course where the professor stressed this type of back transformed parameter estimates represent MEDIAN percent difference due to data being transformed then back transformed into a ratio which is "still" on a different sale than the original in-transformed data. However I cannot find any references to back this up. I also have been told and read conflicting information that the back transformed estimates are MEAN  percent differences.

Can someone please clarify for me. I am by no means a statistician and don't have a strong mathematical background but I would appreciate link to references that specifically address this.

Thank you